# Set different diameters to graph nodes in javascript d3

Tags: d3.js, graph

How can I set different diameters to graph nodes, depend on their 'grade' (by grade I mean root or children)?
For example, I have one source node and I want to set the diameter to a value. Its children will have another value.

This is what I've tried by now:

Here I build the links array:

```
reply.forEach(function (targetNode) {
            links.push({
                source: sourceNode, // the source is a string
                target: targetNode // the target is an array of strings
            });
});
```

And here I tried to give different diameters:

```
.attr("r", function (d) {
                  links.forEach(function (link) {
                      if (d === link.source) {
                          return 15;
                      } else return 6;
                  })
            })
```

The result was a graph only with links, all the nodes disappeared.
Any ideas how can I resolve this?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and click on accept, so that it gets clear that this question is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. If it will help anyone, I leave the code here:

```
function setDiameter() {
            links.forEach(function (link) {
                svg.selectAll("circle")
                    .attr("r", function (d) {
                      if (d === link.source) {
                          return 15;
                      } else return 6;
                })
            });
        }
```